# How to reconcile these two results about the 2D free-particle propagator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, scattering, propagator

The free-particle propagator in 2D is given by
$$ \rho_0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'}, \beta) = \langle \mathbf{r'} \rvert e^{-\beta \hat{H}} \lvert \mathbf{r} \rangle = \frac{1}{4\pi \beta}e^{-\frac{(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'})^2}{4\beta}}$$
where $\hat{H} = -\nabla^2_\mathbf{r}$ is the free-particle Hamiltonian in 2D, and where we assumed $\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} = 1$ and $\beta = \frac{it}{\hbar}$. This expression can easily be derived in Cartesian coordinates, cf my Phys.SE question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/527464/2451).

$$ $$

However, I am facing a two-particle scattering problem, first without interactions. In the center-of-mass frame, the Hamiltonian is the same as the one above with a reduced mass and I am trying to use polar coordinates (since the system has rotational symmetries).

Separating variables and taking only positive-energy solutions with $E=k^2\gt 0$, the wave-function can be written as $\psi(r, \theta) = \Theta_l(\theta)R_{kl}(r)$. The Schrödinger equation yields $\Theta_l(\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{il\theta}$ and $R_{kl}$ is a solution to

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^2R}{\mathrm{d}r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}r} + (k^2-l^2)R=0.$$

A general solution to this equation is given by

$$ R_{kl}(r) = \mathcal{C}_k [\cos\delta_k J_l(kr) + \sin\delta_kY_l(kr)]$$
where $J_l$ and $Y_l$ are Bessel functions of the first and second kind, $\mathcal{C}_k$ is a normalization constant and $\delta_k$ is the phase shift to be determined.

Since there are no interactions between the two particles, the solutions in $Y_l$ (which diverge at $r=0$) should vanish, and therefore $\delta_k = 0$. Furthermore, since $R_{kl}$ is in units of $(\text{distance})^{-1/2}$, we take $\mathcal{C}_k = \sqrt{k}$.

We can now derive the propagator with

$$ \begin{align}\rho_0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'}, \beta) & = \sum_l \sum_k \psi_{k,l}^*(\mathbf{r'}) e^{-\beta E} \psi_{k,l}(\mathbf{r}) \\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_l e^{il(\theta-\theta')}\int_0^\infty k J_l(kr')e^{-\beta k^2} J_l(kr) \mathrm{d}k \\
\rho_0(\mathbf{r},\mathbf{r'}, \beta) & = \frac{1}{4\pi\beta} e^{-\frac{r^2 + r'^2}{4\beta}} \sum_l e^{il(\theta-\theta')} I_l\left(\frac{rr'}{2\beta}\right)
\end{align}$$

where $I_l$ is the modified Bessel function of the first kind. This last integral is given in [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E67). This very much resembles the first equation in the post, but Mathematica says the two are not equal. How can I reconcile the two results?

Comment: An easy sanity check is that, for the correct result, $\lim_{\beta \to 0} \rho_0 = \delta(r - r')$ must hold.